# Image Download to File System Using Generated Name

Tags: c++

I'm using the stb library to edit an image and then I'm trying to save the image to disk. The image making process works perfectly fine, however the name generating process fails and makes files called "mnn" and "mfn". These require me to add the ".png" extension at the end, which then allows me to actually view the image (and they look great btw).

This is my code below:

```
for(unsigned int rep = 0; rep < 3; rep++) {
    //Execute image transformation
    create_square(50, 75, 100, 300, rand()%255, rand()%255, rand()%255);

    char* downloadName = (char *)malloc(sizeof( ("modified_image_" + std::to_string(rep) + ".png").c_str() ));
    *downloadName = *("modified_image_" + std::to_string(rep) + ".png").c_str();

    std::cout << downloadName << " completed." << std::endl;

    //Write modified image to disk
    stbi_write_png(downloadName, width, height, channels, modified_image, width*channels);

    free(downloadName);
}
```

I'm not super sure what I'm doing wrong; this is one of my first times using malloc() and .c_str(), so perhaps I'm missing something obvious.

The "stbi_write_png()" function takes in a "const char *" as the filename(which is the first attribute), which is why I can't just use a std::string.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `malloc` in a C++ program? My crystal ball predicts that there be bugs aplenty.

Comment: `sizeof( ("modified_image_" +....` will be the size of a pointer not the string length.  Please use `std::string`.

Comment: _"I can't just use a std::string"_ Yes, you can. `c_str()` returns a `const char *`. You can pass that to `stbi_write_png`.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I'm writing this comment to answer my own question and mark as answered.

Turns out, I was being dumb! The malloc() was recieving the size of the pointer from .c_str(), which returns a pointer. While I knew this, I was not considering. Now my code reads:

```
for(unsigned int rep = 0; rep < 3; rep++) {
        //Execute image transformation
        create_square(50, 75, 100, 300, rand()%255, rand()%255, rand()%255);

        //Write modified image to disk
        stbi_write_png(("modified_image_" + std::to_string(rep) + ".png").c_str(), width, height, channels, modified_image, width*channels);
    }
```

Which both, well, works and is much cleaner. Thanks folks.

Comment: Wait, I have to wait *two days* to mark my own answer as accepted? That's very silly.